# Using checkboxes to update a total row based on images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, checkbox, html-table

I am working on code which updates a total row based on when a checkbox is checked based on whether or not an image in that row is the correct image.
Here is the HTML:

```
 <table border="1">
    <tr> <!-- Table Header -->
        <td>
            Checkbox
        </td>
        <td>
            Items
        </td>
        <td>
            Area 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Area 2
        </td>
        <td>
            Area 3
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="checkRow"> <!-- Row 1 -->
        <td>
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Row1" value="Row1"  onchange="onCheck(this);">
            </form>     
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 1
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img  id="image1" src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img id="image2" src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img  id="image3" src="no.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- Row 2 -->
        <td>
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Row2" value="Row2"  onchange="onCheck(this);">
            </form>     
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 2
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img  src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img  src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img   src="no.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- Row 3 -->
        <td>
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Row3" value="Row3"  onchange="onCheck(this);">
            </form>     
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 3
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img   src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img  src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img  src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- Row 4 -->
        <td>
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Row4" value="Row4"  onchange="onCheck(this);">
            </form>     
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 4
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img  src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img  src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td class="imageBox">
            <img  src="no.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr id="outputRow"> <!-- Table Bottom -->
        <td>
            <!--Empty-->
        </td>
        <td>
            Summation
        </td>
        <td id="total1">
            0
        </td >
        <td id="total2">
            0
        </td>
        <td id= "total3">
            0
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the Javascript (using jQuery)

```
//Numbers in the total row (Summation)
var total1=0;
var total2=0;
var total3=0;


function onCheck(cb)
     {
         var $box = $(cb);
         var imageBoxes = $box.parents('td.imageBox');
         if(cb.checked===true)
        {

            //Checks the image in the row. If it is yes.png, it adds 1 to to the total
            //for that column and displays that total variable in the total row. 

            /*if(document.getElementById('image1').src.toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                total1++;
                document.getElementById('total1').innerHTML=total1;

            } */
            if(imageBoxes[0].children().attr('src').toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                total1++;
                document.getElementById('total1').innerHTML=total1;

            }
            /*else
            {
                document.getElementById('total1').innerHTML=no;
            } */

            if(document.getElementById('image2').src.toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                total2++;
                document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML=total2;

            } 
           /* else
            {
                document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML=no;
            } */

            if(document.getElementById('image3').src.toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                total3++;
                document.getElementById('total3').innerHTML=total3;

            } 
            /*else
            {
                document.getElementById('total3').innerHTML=no;
            }  */
        }
         //If the checkbox is unchecked, this checks for
         //if the image in each box in that row is
         //yes.png. If it is, then 1 is subtracted from the
         //column's total and the new total is shown.
         else
         {
             if(document.getElementById('image1').src.toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                total1--;
                 document.getElementById('total1').innerHTML=total1;
            } 


            if(document.getElementById('image2').src.toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                total2--;
                document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML=total2;
            } 

            if(document.getElementById('image3').src.toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                total3--;
                document.getElementById('total3').innerHTML=total3; 
            } 


         }
    }
```

I built this in Fiddle, so all the Script imports are not shown.

EDIT: Here is the link to the Fiddle: hhttp://jsfiddle.net/GGxpX/62/
EDIT: It was pointed out that my Id's were repeating. I fixed this in the new fiddle, but this did not fix the problem. 
EDIT3: Fixed more problems including using a td element as its image child. The link points to the updated Fiddle now. 
EDIT4: Updated Fiddle again.

Comment: If you built this as a jsFiddle, why didn't you include the link to it?

Comment: Can you send the link to the jsFiddle?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. The first thing I noticed about your code is that the html markup is invalid: `id` is supposed to be unique - which means your use of `document.getElementById()` won't do what you might want it to. Use `class` rather than `id` if you want to group similar elements.

Comment: another thing i noticed is `imageBoxes[0].attr('src')` is invalid as `imageBoxes` refer's to `td` not `img`

Comment: multitude of problems...input has no parents `imagebox`, `imageBoxes[0]` is a DOM element and can't use jQuery methods on it. Can't repeat ID's in a  page, suggest using index instead. Lastly why are you using inline script and jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. (Correct me if I'm wrong.) I would have the handler for the checkboxes re-calculate the totals each time.

The JavaScript could be this short:

```
function onCheck() {
    var totals = [0, 0, 0];
    $('tr.checkRow').each(function () {
        var $row = $(this);
        if ($row.children('td:first').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked')) {
            $(this).find('td.imageBox').each(function (index) {
                var $imageBox = $(this);
                if ($imageBox.children('img:first').attr('src').indexOf('yes') >= 0) {
                    ++(totals[index]);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#total1').text(totals[0]);
    $('#total2').text(totals[1]);
    $('#total3').text(totals[2]);
}
```

Notice how the `onCheck()` function doesn't even take a parameter. That's because it doesn't matter what checkbox was changed, or if it was checked or unchecked.

This loops through each row, and if its checkbox is checked, it loops through each image box.

In order for the code above to work, you must put the class "checkRow" on the proper `<tr>` elements. (You previously had it as an "id" on those elements.)

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/GGxpX/56/)

There were several things I saw wrong with your code. Here's a few:

1. "id" attributes must be unique.
2. When checking the result of calling `.indexOf()` use `>= 0`, not `> 0`.
3. `imageBoxes[0]` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object.
4. There is no need for the calls to `toString()` because the `src` attribute is a string.

You could also attach your event handlers with jQuery, rather than use "onchange" attributes, but I left it your way in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks to all of you who replied to my question. Special thanks to John S who gave me a working version of what I am trying to do. I will examine all that I have done wrong and can do to learn how to make better code in the future.